# Magento - Where are Order Item details for Order, Invoice, Creditmemo and Shipment Pdfs

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to access Order Item Details (eg SKU) for Order, Invoice, Creditmemo and Shipment Pdfs. I cant locate where to access it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Loveleen
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for rendering these in the relevant PDFs sit in

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items
```

There are Creditmemo, Invoice and Shipment folders that hold the code for the different types of items

Comment: Thanks CCBlackburn - I found it in the files you indicated.